# How to automatically track a remote branch when creating a local branch with the same name?

Tags: git, settings, git-remote

I am using Git on several machines. I must have a configuration, which defers on one of the machines, because in the scenario, where I am on `master` and have a remote branch `origin/foo` and want to create a local branch `foo`, which tracks the remote branch the following happens:

- on most of the machines the command I need to use is (while on `master`):

  ```
  git checkout -b foo origin/foo
  ```
- however on one of the machines it suffices if I just use:

  ```
  git checkout -b foo
  ```

In both cases I get

```
Branch foo set up to track remote branch foo from origin.
```

However, the second command works only on one of my machines and on the rest of them it just checks out a local branch `foo`. Why is that and which setting is responsible for it to work?

P.S. I did the following things, which didn't help:

- updated to git v. 2.1.3;
- made sure I have only one remote;
- fetched the remote branches with `git fetch origin`

**UPDATE** The information that on one of the machines `git checkout -b foo` works is false. The correct command to checkout a local branch to track a remote is `git checkout foo` without `-b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the git version is an older one.

Recent versions of Git should always create a tracking branch with [`git checkout -b`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to

```
git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

(or `foo` is present in more than one remote)
(or you didn't fetch from that remote yet, and it didn't detect the presence of the remote tracking branch `origin/foo`)

However, it uses `git checkout foo`, not `git checkout -b foo`, as the [OP Alex Popov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1836143/alex-popov) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815429/how-to-automatically-track-a-remote-branch-when-creating-a-local-branch-with-the/26815451#comment42202524_26815451).

Comment: Alas, updating `git` from 1.9.1 to 2.1.3 didn't help me, I updated my question. It's a kind of a strange problem...

Comment: @AlexPopov is the `foo` branch present in your .git/refs/remotes/origin folder?

Comment: @AlexPopov withthe very same name (no trailing space for instance)?

Comment: @AlexPopov could you try (in a new clone) a `git checkout foo` (instead of `git checkout -b foo`) to see if that works better?

Comment: No trailing whitespace. Yes, let me try that with the new clone.

Comment: Sorry for waisting your time. In both repos (old and new clone) `git checkout foo` works. My mistake was adding `-b` to the checkout command. Once again, sorry for your time.